# Being apprised of when NSStatusItem is hidden

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsstatusitem

I have an app which uses an `NSStatusItem`. On small screens there's not much space in the status bar. When a user switches to an application with a lot of menu items, my status item gets hidden. Is there a way to get notified about this?

What I tried so far:

- I checked if any `NSNotification` is fired: No
- I checked if the `statusView` is removed from the view hierarchy: No
- I checked `isHiddenOrHasHiddenAncestor`: No

Here's the code I use to create the status item.

```
self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
MyStatusView *maView = [[[MyStatusView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 22)] autorelease];
[statusItem setTitle:@"Ma Status Item"];
[statusItem setView:maView];
```

Comment: can you test whether its view.center property changes as it moves off the screen? You might be able to add KVO notification to the center property to establish a sort of callback, but I don't know if that would work for a statusItem.

Comment: I also have a timer running that logs the bounds relative to the window. Not changing... It looks like maView is in it's own window (NSWindow > NSNextStepFrame > maView). Will try and see if this is moved off screen.

Comment: Window bounds are also still on screen. The window might be overlaid by something else. Don't know how to check for this though..

Comment: I figured that the status item is hidden by moving it's window into the background. I ran a timer that checks the windows on top of maView.window like this https://gist.github.com/1282781. Now someone tell me if there's a notification when a Window is moved to the background.

Comment: @stigi did you end up getting this to work? I can't seem to get the notifications dragoncharmer listed to fire.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty smart of you to realize that when a status item is hidden, its window will be moved into the background.

Now the notification you're looking for is:
[NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification)
(or [NSWindowDidResignMainNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWindowDidResignMainNotification) depending on the context of your application)

For a clear explanation about the difference between a key window and a main window, see [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/59019-difference-between-main-and-key-attribute-for-window.html).

Comment: This answer doesn't work, -1, no notifications of that sort are sent when an NSStatusItem is hidden

Comment: -1: I second @Vervious - this answer is worse than useless, it caused me to waste my time trying to make it work.